# Existential quantification over regular predicates

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, computability-theory, formal-languages

A regular language over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is a subset of the set of all words over $\Sigma$ that can be accepted by some finite automaton. A regular language identifies a certain property of strings of $\Sigma^*$.

One can then define a regular predicate over $\Sigma^*$

as an n-ary relation on $\Sigma^*$ such that by suitably coding n-tuples of words as single words (see for example Blumensath and Gradel) one obtains a regular language (over a new alphabet). If $R(x,y)$ is a regular binary predicate, what can be the status of the unary predicate $\exists x.R(x,y)$? (again regular, decidable, r.e., or what else?)

Comment: The set '$\{ y : (\exists x)[R(x,y)] \}$' is also regular. This is a consequence of the more general fact that if $S$ is a regular set, then any set first-order definable from $S$ is regular. Indeed, all sets that are definable from $S$ in a first-order manner together with the quantifier "there exists infinitely many" and the quantifiers "there exist $k$-many mod $n$" is regular.

Comment: Asher, I would recommend you to post your comment as an answer, especially if you could sketch the proof (e.g. by mentioning how the pumping lemma allows you to cut the existential search down).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know why I've never seen this kind of closure property being treated in a formal language/computability theory course, while it is always explained for the case of recursively enumerable predicates.

@Joel: thanks for your point, I would like to see a sketch of the proof. Can it be found in some textbook? I think it would be nice to show this to students.

Comment: Can one not prove this from the equivalence of MSO with regular languages?

Comment: I looked up on google the issue of MSO definability of regular languages. The result which is reported everywhere (that of Buchi) is based on an interpretation of individual variables as natural numbers and of set-variables as sets of natural numbers (to be understood as positions in words). 
The semantics is then
$ w,I,J \models \phi$
where $w$ is a word, $I$ is a valuation of individual variables, $J$ is a valuation of set-variables and $\phi$ is a formula.
I was referring to a straightforward interpretation of individual variables as words. Are the answers still valid?

Comment: I am not a logician but it seems like you can build an MO expression from your predicate. Straubing does this with unary predicates in his book. 

Comment: @Joel Why do you want to use the pumping lemma? Pumping arguments are used to prove that a language is not regular. In this case there is simply a straight-forward construction of an automaton for the projection of $R$ given an automaton for $R$.

Comment: @Joel - Yes, please, if you could explain your remark, I would also be very interested to hear.  Um, using small words if possible - I came here after not understanding the discussion in "Word processing in groups".  Thanks!

Comment: User and Sam, I had meant only that the proof uses what I see as essentially the same idea as the proof of the pumping lemma. To my way of thinking, the fundamental phenomenon here is that what one might expect to be an unbounded infinite search is reduced to an essentially finite search, because one is searching only for witnesses that obey the given regular language; this is essentially the same thing going on in the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a reference for the answer. It should be in the following paper:

S. Eilemberg, C.C. Elgot, J.C. Shepherdson, Sets recognized by n-tape automata, Journal of Algebra, vol. 13, (1969), pp. 447-464.

Unfortunately I cannot download it from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

That is a central point about automatic structures: By projection (“existential quantification”) you get another regular predicate, and regular predicates are also closed under intersection and complementation. Consequently, the first-order theories of automatic structures are decidable (because you can decide for a given automaton whether he accepts any word).

The proof is quite simple: You want to project $x$ away—just simulate every possible input for $x$ in parallel using sets of states of the old automaton as states for the new automaton (it remains a finite state machine, since the power set of a finite set is finite).

As conjectured above you can also prove it using the MSO translation, let me sketch it: You have regular predicate $R(x,y)$ defined using a MSO formula. This MSO formula uses relation symbols $X_{(a,b)}$ to refer to “the set of positions where $x$ has character $a$ and $y$ has character $b$”. For the projection add existential second-order quantifiers $\exists Q_1\ldots Q_n$ (where $\Sigma=\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$) and replace the occurencesof $X_{(a,b)}$ by $X_b\wedge Q_a$ and add an expression expressing that the sets $Q_a$ build a partition. This is not yet correct, because it does not consider different lengths of $x$ and $y$ and we have to deal with some trailing characters, but that is as easy. However–the whole MSO-based proof is much more complicated than constructing an automaton directly.

Notice that both proofs can be transfered to $\omega$-automata and finite and infinite tree-automata.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is Theorem 1.4.6 (predicate calculus) in the book "Word processing in groups".  However, I find their discussion somewhat confusing -- I came here hoping for a better reference...